# Issue with Python statsmodels requirement in Docker image build

Tags: python, docker, numpy, dockerfile, statsmodels

I'm trying to build a Docker image for an AWS Batch job, but a new requirement (the Python package `statsmodels`) is breaking my build process.

`requirements.txt` lines:

```
pandas
numpy
statsmodels
```

Complete `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

COPY requirements.txt /home/
COPY .env /home/
COPY src home/src
COPY process.py /home/

WORKDIR /home/
ENV TZ=America/New_York
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH='.'
```

Error log excerpts:

```
#12 271.7 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#12 288.4 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of us to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#12 288.4 Collecting us
#12 288.4   Downloading us-2.0.1.tar.gz (13 kB)
#12 288.8   Downloading us-2.0.0.tar.gz (13 kB)
#12 289.3   Downloading us-1.0.0.tar.gz (13 kB)
#12 289.8   Downloading us-0.9.1.tar.gz (13 kB)
#12 290.2   Downloading us-0.9.0.tar.gz (13 kB)
#12 290.6   Downloading us-0.8.0.tar.gz (12 kB)
#12 291.2   Downloading us-0.7.1.tar.gz (12 kB)
#12 291.5 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#12 291.5 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of us to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#12 291.6   Downloading us-0.7.tar.gz (11 kB)
#12 291.9   Downloading us-0.6.tar.gz (9.9 kB)
#12 292.3   Downloading us-0.5.tar.gz (9.3 kB)
#12 292.7   Downloading us-0.4.tar.gz (9.3 kB)
#12 293.0   Downloading us-0.3.tar.gz (7.5 kB)
#12 293.4 INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
#12 293.4 INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
#12 293.4   Downloading us-0.2.tar.gz (6.9 kB)
#12 294.0   Downloading us-0.1.tar.gz (6.3 kB)
#12 294.4 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of statsmodels to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#12 294.9 Collecting statsmodels
#12 294.9   Downloading statsmodels-0.12.0.tar.gz (17.5 MB)
#12 297.5   Installing build dependencies: started
#12 309.5   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#12 309.5   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#12 392.2   Getting requirements to build wheel: still running...
#12 400.0   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#12 400.1     Preparing wheel metadata: started
#12 401.3     Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
#12 401.9   Downloading statsmodels-0.11.1.tar.gz (15.4 MB)
#12 404.2   Installing build dependencies: started
#12 415.7   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#12 415.7   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#12 480.8   Getting requirements to build wheel: still running...
#12 481.5   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#12 481.5     Preparing wheel metadata: started
#12 482.6     Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
#12 483.1   Downloading statsmodels-0.11.0.tar.gz (15.4 MB)
#12 485.5   Installing build dependencies: started
#12 488.6   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
#12 488.6   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#12 488.6    command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-_0xxe4fy/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.29.14' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.5; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"'' 'scipy>=1.0'
#12 488.6        cwd: None
#12 488.6   Complete output (13 lines):
#12 488.6   Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
#12 488.6   Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
#12 488.6   ERROR: Cannot install numpy==1.14.5 and numpy==1.17.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
#12 488.6   
#12 488.6   The conflict is caused by:
#12 488.6       The user requested numpy==1.14.5
#12 488.6       The user requested numpy==1.17.5
#12 488.6   
#12 488.6   To fix this you could try to:
#12 488.6   1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
#12 488.6   2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
#12 488.6   
#12 488.6   ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
#12 488.6   ----------------------------------------
#12 488.6 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-_0xxe4fy/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.29.14' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.5; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"'' 'scipy>=1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r ./requirements.txt]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

---

Updated `Dockerfile` per comments:

```
FROM debian:10-slim

# install Python, pip, and misc build needs
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        build-essential \
        python3-dev \
        python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
    && apt-get clean

# bring in program logic
COPY .env /root/.env  # this may need to go into /root/.env (or a custom user)
COPY src /app/
COPY processer.py submit-processer.py /app/
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

# set env vars
ENV TZ=America/New_York

# running process logic
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "processer.py"]
```

Error log of updated process:

```
[+] Building 0.7s (7/12)                                                        
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 979B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:10-slim          0.6s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 15.91kB                                       0.0s
 => CANCELED [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/debian:10-slim@sha256:062bbd9a1  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/debian:10-slim@sha256:062bbd9a1a58c9c5b8  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install --no-install-r  0.0s
 => ERROR [3/8] COPY .env /root/.env  # this may need to go into /root/.e  0.0s
------
 > [3/8] COPY .env /root/.env  # this may need to go into /root/.env (or a custom user):
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/#" not found: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear why from your Dockerfile (I'm surprised the tag `3` isn't sufficient to just pick the latest stable of `3.9.1-buster`), but `pip` is trying to resolve dependencies for several versions of Python (implying there are several installed in the base container)

> #12 488.6 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-_0xxe4fy/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.29.14' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.5; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"'' 'scipy>=1.0' Check the logs for full command output.

Specifying a minor version may clear this up.

If you don't have a particular version need, [`3.8-slim-buster`](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) (Debian 10 with Python 3.8 .. actually 3.8.9 *for now* though this may change with bug fixes to that version) may be a practical choice and fix this for you!

```
from python:3.8-slim-buster
...
```

---

If this does not fix the error, then it's likely your `3` tag is just fine and instead extremely-likely that your `.env` is problematic (presumably it's a Python virtual environment you are trying to preserve).

Regenerate the venv within the context of your container with a new `RUN` block rather than `COPY`-ing what your host system has.

---

After the comments, I think it's worth trying a different Dockerfile which is much more what I would use with at least the following changes

- base directly off Debian 10 (you may find another container is more efficient/smaller/whatever, but it's extremely likely this works out of the box)
- install Python 3 yourself
- don't use `/home/` as a base

```
FROM debian:10-slim

# install Python, pip, and misc build needs
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        build-essential \
        python3-dev \
        python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
    && apt-get clean

# bring in program logic
COPY .env /app/  # this may need to go into /root/.env (or a custom user)
COPY src /app/
COPY process.py /app/
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

# set env vars
ENV TZ=America/New_York

# running process logic
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "process.py"]
```

If this works

- using `/home` may be problematic (rather than `/home/someuser/...`)
- there could be something weird with the upstream `python` base container (I have never personally used it, though that would also be surprising)

If this does not work

- you may not be working in the directory you think you are (ie. copying the *current* directory in, another similar-looking directory, etc.)
- your `src` may have something bizarre in it
- `statsmodels` may be broken (it's versioned 0.12, so that's not totally unreasonable)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. In trying to run with `3.8-slim-buster`, I get a similar error, but now `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. My `.env` in this case is merely two lines specifying Airtable API arguments (AIRTABLE_BASE=xxx...), no venv.

Comment: Mysterious - try removing `PYTHONPATH` and calling simply `python3` rather than any reference to `/usr/local`

Comment: Hmm upon removing the `PYTHONPATH` line and calling `RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` I return to the error as logged in the initial post... any other ideas?

Comment: @OJT I made a big edit with another Dockerfile and some thoughts, which may work for you

Comment: I've updated my Dockerfile contents and error log in the question. I'm not particularly experienced with this stuff in general; what exactly is the difference here, and how might it affect running in an AWS Batch EC2 instance environment (e.g., using `/app/` vs. the instance `/home/` directory as we use successfully in other Dockerized processes that don't require `statsmodels`?

Comment: Also, it seems I get the error regarding `.env` directory even after changing it to `/root/.env`*